# Difference between "gcc -x c" and "gcc -x c++" assembly output

Tags: gcc, assembly, g++

I have the following code in file main.c:

```
int main() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this with `gcc -x c -m32 -S -O0 -o main.s main.c` (under Fedora 16 64-bit) I get this output:

```
    .file   "main.c"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    subl    $16, %esp
    movl    $0, -4(%ebp)
    jmp .L2
.L3:
    addl    $1, -4(%ebp)
.L2:
    cmpl    $4, -4(%ebp)
    jle .L3
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.6.2 20111027 (Red Hat 4.6.2-1)"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

However, when I use `gcc -x c++ -m32 -S -O0 -o main.s main.c` I get the same output except for these lines:

```
.L2:
    cmpl    $4, -4(%ebp)
    setle   %al
    testb   %al, %al
    jne .L3
```

My question is: why does it use `setle` and `testb` instead of `jle` in C++ code? Is it more effective?

P.S. Also, is there a way to get rid of these `.cfi_*` directives in an assembly output?

Comment: Since you've disabled optimization, why would you care if one is more "effective" than the other?  Try comparing optimized output.  As far as getting rid of the `.cfi`, just compile to an object and then disassemble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you're using a different compiler, so it's not really that surprising that you get different output.  `clang` does happen to give exactly the same results when compiling your program as C or C++, if that's of interest to you:

```
$ cp example.c example.cpp
$ clang -o exampleC example.c
$ clang++ -o exampleC++ example.cpp
$ otool -tV exampleC > C
$ otool -tV exampleC++ > C++
$ diff C C++
1c1
< exampleC:
---
> exampleC++:
$
```

I get the same results from `gcc` and `g++` on my machine as well, so it looks like it's just a quirk of your particular compiler version.